# ST_GeomFromText in Where Clause SQL

Tags: postgis

Can I use `ST_Geom_from_Text` in a where clause? Specifically:

```
Select column from schema.table where  ST_DWithin( ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((-71.1776585052917 42.3902909739571,-71.1776820268866 42.3903701743239,-71.1776063012595 42.3903825660754,-71.1775826583081 42.3903033653531,-71.1776585052917 42.3902909739571))'), the_geom)
```

Postgre seems to throw an error at the bracket right after ST_GeomFromText .

Here i am trying to find all the points in the table inside the given polygon - table has geometry column the_geom .

Comment: You don't have a where clause in the query. I can't see how this is a useful contribution on the site. Seems like a typo.

Comment: This is the correct behavior for an invalid query. 1) ST_DWithin takes three or four parameters, not two -- You probably meant ST_Within  2) Your WKT string is incorrectly assembled (unless you really are searching Antarctica, a few thousand miles south of the Mozmbique Channel) -- the order is 'X Y' (which is 'longitude latitude') 3) ST_GeomFromText ought to have two arguments, the second being the SRID (4326); if this isn't the SRID of your the_geom column, you need to reproject as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this query :

```
Select * from yourtable WHERE ST_DWithin( ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((-71.1776585052917 42.3902909739571,-71.1776820268866 42.3903701743239,-71.1776063012595 42.3903825660754,-71.1775826583081 42.3903033653531,-71.1776585052917 42.3902909739571))'), the_geom , 500)
```

The ST_DWithin function takes exactly three parameters : http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html

A) There was no WHERE clause, that was the mistake.

B) You can try with this query which use and set a srid for your specific polygon :

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourtable 
WHERE ST_DWithin( 
    setsrid(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((-71.1776585052917 42.3902909739571,-71.1776820268866 42.3903701743239,-71.1776063012595 42.3903825660754,-71.1775826583081 42.3903033653531,-71.1776585052917 42.3902909739571))'),4326)
    , st_transform(the_geom,4326) , 
    100
    );
```

The table "yourtable" must have too an srid.
I hope it will be usefull

Comment: Doesnt ST_GeomFromText give an SRID to the polygon created ? I mean what is the SRID of the polygon created by running ST_GeomFromText                      ('POLYGON((-71.1776585052917 42.3902909739571,-71.1776820268866 42.3903701743239,-71.1776063012595 42.3903825660754,-71.1775826583081 42.3903033653531,-71.1776585052917 42.3902909739571))

Comment: In the second query I apply the setsrid() function with the SRID : 4326. It's like the WGS 84, or LAT/LONG coordinates ; You can use it.

Comment: I think ST_GeomFromText creates geometry with default srid (-1) so it has to be defined if your other data has srid (not default -1 also know as "not defined" )